# When is a faithful ideal of a unital commutative ring a regular ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. We denote by $\mathrm{Ann}(I)$ the *annihilator of $I$*, that is
$\mathrm{Ann}(I) \Doteq \{ r \in R \, \vert \, rI = \{0\}\}$.

We say that $I$ is a *faithful ideal* of $R$ if $\mathrm{Ann}(I) = \{0\}$.
We call $r \in R$ a *regular element* of $R$, if it is not a zero divisor, i.e., if $\mathrm{Ann}(Rr) = \{0\}$.

We say that $I$ is *regular* ideal of $R$ if $I$ contains a regular element. A regular ideal is clearly a faithful ideal.

> **Question 1.** Do you know of an example of a two-generated ideal which is faithful but not regular?
>
> **Question 2.** If such an example does exist, then under which conditions is a finitely generated faithful ideal also regular?

Comment: My dissertation asked a more general question than this (concerning modules.)  In short, I never found an example or proof either way either for the special case of ideals.  If a counterexample exists, it would be extremely interesting to me.

Comment: I am particulary interested in the case of $a = 2$ and $b$ can be any ring element. Does that change anything? And is it more likely that the claim holds?

Comment: The answer has been given here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341760/if-anna-and-annb-intersect-in-the-zero-ideal-is-it-true-that-a-b-contains?noredirect=1#comment854333_341760 by Luc Guyot.

Comment: Thank you... I will consult that resource. By the way, it is considered bad form to crosspost to both here and mathoverflow without reason (for example, a question could turn out to be too hard here, and so it might be worthwhile posting there.)

Comment: It posted it there because it was not answered here. Should i mark it next time or how is it done normaly?

Comment: After posting in the place you think best, you wait. If after a week there isn't any progress in comments or any solutions, then you could consider crossposting, and you'd be sure to link the two.  At any rate, one should be up front about the fact they're crossposting.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer.

Comment: The corresponding Mathoverflow question has been closed. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [1], we say that a ring $R$ satisfies Property (A) if every finitely generated faithful ideal of $R$ is regular.

> **Claim 1**. [1, Section 2] Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring.
>
> - If the zero ideal of $R$ has a primary decomposition in $R$ then $R$ has Property (A). In particular, any Noetherian ring has Property (A).
> - If $R$ is zero-dimensional, then $R$ has Property (A).

Thus a counter-example should be a non-Noetherian ring of positive Krull dimension, should this dimension be well-defined.

We present now an example, due to D. Anderson and J. Pascual, of a ring $R$ with a two-generated faithful ideal $I$ which is not regular.
This construction relies on Nagata's *idealization method*. Given a commutative unital ring $S$ and an $S$-module $A$, we define the commutative ring $R \Doteq S \oplus A$ with identity $(1, 0)$ by $$(s, a) \cdot (s', a') \Doteq (ss', sa' + s'a).$$
We can identify (and we will) $S$ with the subring $S \oplus \{0\}$ of $R$.

It is easily seen that $Z(S \oplus A) = \{(s, a) \, \vert \, s \in Z(S) \cup Z(A)\}$ where $Z(R)$ is the set of zero divisors of $R$ and $Z(A) \Doteq \{ s \in S \, \vert \, sa = 0 \text{ for some non-zero } a \in A \}$. If $S$ is an integral domain and $\mathcal{P}$ is a set of prime ideals of $S$ and $A = \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p} \in \mathcal{P}} S/\mathfrak{p}$, then $Z(A) = \bigcup_{\mathfrak{p} \in \mathcal{P}} \mathfrak{p}$. Thus, if the set $S \setminus S^{\times}$ of non-units of $S$ is covered by the prime ideals in $\mathcal{P}$, then $(s, a) \in R = S \oplus A$ is regular if and only if $s$ is a unit of$S$. This covering property holds for instance if $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of height one prime ideals of $S$ for $S$ a Noetherian normal domain [2, Theorem 11.5].

> **Claim 2**. [1, Example 2.1] Let $k$ be a field and let $S = k[X, Y]$ be the polynomial ring over two variables with coefficients in $k$. Let $A = \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}}S/\mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ ranges over the height one prime ideals of $S$. Let $R = S \oplus A$ be the idealization of $A$. Let $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $(X, 0)$ and $(Y, 0)$. Then $I$ is faithful but no regular.

Showing that $I$ is faithful will be easy. In order to show that any element of $I$ is a zero divisor, the important fact to note is that $S \setminus S^{\times}$ is covered by the height one prime ideals of $S$.

> *Proof of Claim 2*.
>
> Let us show first that $I$ is faithful. Consider $r = (s, a) \in R$ such that $rI = \{0\}$. Since $S$ is a domain, it is trivial to check that $s = 0$. Let us write $a = (a_{\mathfrak{p}} + \mathfrak{p})_{\mathfrak{p}}$ with $a_{\mathfrak{p}} \in S$. Since $Xa = Ya = 0$, we have $a_{\mathfrak{p}} \in \mathfrak{p}$ for every $\mathfrak{p}$ distinct from $(X)$ and $(Y)$. As $Y a_{(X)} \in (X)$ and $Xa_{(Y)} \in (Y)$, we deduce that $a = 0$.
>
> Let us prove now that every element of $I$ is a zero-divisor of $R$. Since $S$ is a Noetherian [normal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain) (it is actually a Noetherian [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain)), every non-unit $s$ of $S$ is contained in some height one prime ideal of $S$ [2, Theorem 11.5]. As every element $r$ of $I$ is of the form $(s, a)$ with $s \in (X, Y)$, every such $r$ is a zero-divisor by the remark preceding the claim . Indeed, take $\mathfrak{q}$ a prime of height one that contains $s$ and let $\delta_{\mathfrak{q}} \in A$ be defined by $(\delta_{\mathfrak{q}})_{\mathfrak{p}} = 1 + \mathfrak{p}$ if $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{q}$ and $(\delta_{\mathfrak{q}})_{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathfrak{p}$ otherwise. Then we have $(s, a) \cdot (0, \delta_{\mathfrak{q}}) = (0, 0).$

---

[1] D. Anderson and J. Pascual, "Regular ideals in commutative rings, sublattices of regular ideals, and Prüfer rings", 1987.
[2] D. Eisenbud, "Commutative algebra with a view towards geometric algebra", 1995.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not true in general. See ''F. Azarpanah,  O. A. S.  Karamzadeh and  A.  Rezai Aliabad,  On ideals consisting entirely of
zero divisors, $\textit{Comm. Algebra} \textbf{28}$ (2000)
1061--1073.'' for more information. The following lemma may be useful.

Lemma: Let $R$ be a reduced ring and $a, b\in R$ such that $ ab=0$. Then
$Ann_R(\langle a, b\rangle)= Ann_R(a-b)$.

Proof:
Clearly $Ann_R(\langle a, b\rangle)\subseteq Ann_R(a-b)$. Now
let $r\in Ann_R(a-b)$. Thus, $ra=rb$, and so $(ra)^2=0$. Hence,
$rb=ra=0$, and so $Ann_R(\langle a, b\rangle)\supseteq
Ann_R(a-b)$.

Comment: In your example we always have $r\in \text{Ann}(a) \cap \text{Ann}(b)$ so in particular $\text{Ann}(a) \cap \text{Ann}(b) \neq \{0\}$ if $r\neq 0$. I do not understand how one can construct a counterexample like this.